# gcc 4.7.2 in Debian wheezy doesn't always properly align stack pointer. Is this a bug?

Tags: c, gcc, calling-convention

Casually, when reading the assembler listing of a sample C program, I noted that the stack pointer is not 16 bit aligned before calling function foo:

```
void foo() { }
int func(int p) { foo(); return p; }  
int main() { return func(1); }

func:  
  pushq %rbp
  movq  %rsp, %rbp
  subq  $8, %rsp          ; See here
  movl  %edi, -4(%rbp)
  movl  $0, %eax
  call  foo
  movl  -4(%rbp), %eax
  leave
  ret
```

The `subq $8, %rsp` instruction makes RSP not aligned before calling foo (it should be "subq $16, %rsp").
In System V ABI, par. 3.2.2, I read: "the value (%rsp − 8) is always a multiple of 16 when control is transferred to the function entry point".
Someone can help me to understand why gcc doesn't put `subq $16, %rsp` ?
Thank you in advance.

Edit:
I forgot to mention my OS and compiler version:
Debian wheezy, gcc 4.7.2

Comment: Perhaps it's because the `call func` instruction that got you there already pushed something onto the stack, as did the `pushq %rbp`. There may also have been other instructions before the `call` that pushed arguments, etc...

Comment: Perhaps it's meant to be _16 bits_?  As in, a multiple of 16 bits, meaning aligned on words (two bytes).  From my experience, this is how the stack pointer just has to be... even.  Odd values are right out!

Comment: @lornix.  No. alignment is in bytes.  You can specify a preferred value to compiler (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx or http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html).  If you try disassembling other code you will notice that the stack pointer is always multiple of 16 bytes.  I don't understand why in the simple example I posted this is not true.

Comment: @twalberg.  No.  Assembler listing of main() shows that the stack pointer is 16 byte aligned before calling func(): "pushq %rbp", "movq %rsp, %rbp", "movl $1, %edi", "call func".  I assume that rsp is correctly (16 byte) aligned when main() starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Assuming that the stack pointer is 16-byte aligned when `func` is entered, then the combination of</strike>

```
pushq %rbp              ; <- 8 bytes
movq  %rsp, %rbp
subq  $8, %rsp          ; <- 8 bytes
```

will keep it 16-byte aligned for the subsequent call to `foo()`.

It seems that since the compiler knows about the implementation of `foo()` and that it's a noop, it's not bothering with the stack alignment. If `foo()` is seen as only a declaration or prototype in the translation unit where `func()` is compiled you'll see your expected stack alignment.

Comment: @Burr.  No: the "call func" instruction pushed rip (8 bytes) on the stack, then the "pushq %rbp" makes rsp 16-byte aligned.  But the next "subq $8, %rsp" makes rsp not correctly aligned.  Try adding "putchar('A');" in foo() and func() will correct to "subq $16, %rsp"

Comment: I see now.  I think what's happening is that since the compiler knows about the implementation of `foo()` and that it's a noop, it's not bothering with the stack alignment.  If `foo()` is implemented in another translation unit, you'll see your expected stack alignment. I'm not sure why this occurs even in "non-optimized" code.